# How to delete mutiple documents by ID in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete a short list of documents in one swoop on Elasticsearch 2.4, and I can't seem to give it a query that results in >0 documents getting deleted.

```
id_list = ["AWeKNmt5qJi-jqXwc6qO", "AWeKT7ULqJi-jqXwc6qS"] #example

# The following does not delete any document (despite these ids being valid)
delres = es.delete_by_query("my_index", doc_type="my_doctype", body={
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "_id": id_list
        }
    }
})
```

If I go one by one, then they get deleted just fine. Which seems to point to my query being the problem.

```
for the_id in id_list:
    es.delete("my_index", doc_type="my_doctype", id=the_id)
```

I've also tried the `ids` query instead of `terms`, but that also does not delete anything.

```
es.delete_by_query(..., body = {"query": {"ids" { "values": id_list }}})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`delete_by_query` was deprecated in ES 1.5.3, removed in ES 2.0, and reintroduced in ES 5.0. From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-delete-by-query.html:

> Delete by Query will be removed in 2.0: it is problematic since it silently forces a refresh which can quickly cause OutOfMemoryError during concurrent indexing, and can also cause primary and replica to become inconsistent. Instead, use the scroll/scan API to find all matching ids and then issue a bulk request to delete them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, since I'm still getting a 200 response for that API in v2.4, which according to the blurb, shouldn't even be there.

Looks like [bulk delete operation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers) might be the way to go on 2.4 then. Also, am I to believe, from your answer, that my usage of `delete_by_query` would be otherwise correct against a more recent version, e.g. 6.5?